# BroadcastReceiver not handling BOOT_COMPLETED

Tags: android

Here's my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<application>
    <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Here's my class MyBroadcastReceiver.java:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("TAG", "this is onReceive");
```

I'm using Android Studio 1.4 on Windows with the emulator. I'm not getting anything in my log.

Comment: Do you have an activity? Did you launch that activity before attempting to reboot your device or emulator?

Comment: I have a main (launcher) activity. I just press play in android studio and expect my broadcast to work. This is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just press play in android studio and expect my broadcast to work. This is wrong?

Yes, this is wrong.

First, Android Studio will only run an activity, specifically a launcher activity. Android Studio will not, on its own, send broadcasts.

Second, `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` is broadcast when a device or emulator has rebooted (or is powered on from having been completely off). Running an app in Android Studio does not reboot a device or emulator. Running an app in Android Studio can *boot* an emulator, however your app will not be installed on the emulator until after that boot process has occurred and the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast has been sent.

Comment: This explains. I wanted to start a service from the receiver. My solution is now to start that service from the receiver *and* from the onCreate event of my main activity (unless it's already started). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to send a broadcast to your application from adb:

```
 adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
```